# AWS S3 configure sub-domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using Amazon's simple storage service (S3). I noticed that others like Trello were able to configure sub-domain for their S3 links. In the following link they have `trello-attachments` as sub-domain.

`https://trello-attachments.s3.amazonaws.com/.../.../..../file.png`

Where can I configure this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to configure it.

All buckets work that way if there are no dots in the bucket name and it's otherwise a hostname made up of valid characters.  If your bucket isn't in the "US-Standard" region, you may have to use the [correct endpoint](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region) instead of ".s3.amazonaws.com" to avoid a redirect (or to make it work at all).

> An ordinary Amazon S3 REST request specifies a bucket by using the first slash-delimited component of the Request-URI path. Alternatively, you can use Amazon S3 virtual hosting to address a bucket in a REST API call by using the HTTP Host header. In practice, Amazon S3 interprets Host as meaning that most buckets are automatically accessible (for limited types of requests) at http://*bucketname*.s3.amazonaws.com.
>
> <sup>— http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html</sup>